# How to catch a copy event on a web-page with Chrome extension running in the background?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've tried for hours to find a solution for a Chrome extension to be able to listen to a copy event on a regular website. So far the closest I've been to a solution has been when I created this event script:

```
function onCopy(e) {
    console.log("onCopy works"); //it doesn't :(
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({event: "copy"});
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage('copy', onCopy, true);
```

The function at oncopy.js is supposed to send a message to a function like this in popup.js:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.event == "copy") {
            console.log("copy detected");
        }
        sendResponse({});
    });
```

Unfortunately, the message created by console.log("onCopy works") is the only thing that works. I'd really appreciate if someone could clarify what I'm doing wrong, and what I'm not doing. The goal here is to get data from clipboard everytime user makes a copy an event. Here's the relevant part of my manifest.json in case it helps:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["oncopy.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
```

Comment: Background page is not related to the web page and can't listen to DOM events. You need a content script. Make sure to read the extension architecture article in the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, I forgot to read it (this is my first Chrome extension) and it really explained a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your message handler is in `popup.js` and it is actually a script inside your `popup.html` then it will work only when popup is opened.
Even if it is in background page - it won't display alerts. You should use `console.log` and open background page in DevTools to see the result.
Also you need [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage) and [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage) to send and receive messages between content scripts and popup/background pages:

```js
// in background pagage or in popup page (works only when popup is opened)
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("received: " + request);
    sendResponse("message has been processed by background page");
});

// in content script injected into website page
document.addEventListener("copy", () =>
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        { event: "click" },
        msg => console.log(msg)))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I almost got it to work and I updated the question details. Could you possibly tell me what's not working on the onCopy function?

Comment: @xis - I added example how you can handle this

Comment: It works, thank you so much for taking all of this time to helping out!